# Finite subgroups of $PSL(2,R)$

Tags: group-theory, group-presentation

I know $PSL(2,R)$ is $SL(2,R)/SZ(2,R)$ and it is a simple group, but I do not have single clue how to get on finding its group presentation. How can I find its presentation and also I am looking for what its finite subgroups (or all subgroups) look like. Is there any characterization for finite subgroups of $PSL(2,R)$, any reference to some journal where they have been studied and classified?

Comment: A real representation of a finite group admits an invariant symmetric bilinear form. So a finite subgroup of ${\rm SL}(2,{\mathbb R})$ is orthogonal and hence consists of rotations and must be cyclic. So I think the answer is all finite cyclic groups.